# Assigning a variable length to setInterval() on a per-case basis

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm currently trying to adapt [this project by Nutty7t](https://codepen.io/nutty7t/pen/qzzGOR) into a more versatile simulation of Persona 5's SMS system. I have made progress given my previous experiences designing websites (in High School I revamped by history teacher's in-class sites).

As of now I have implemented a system that simulates multiple individuals participating in the text conversation. Each message has a variable identifying who it is sent from, and it grabs the corresponding character's text icon to display.

There are two things I have yet to simulate:

- First off is how long it is before the next message - as it stands all messages are displayed 2000ms apart. It works but it feels off, and I'd like to figure out how to set the interval on a per message basis.
- Second, some indication participant(s) are typing.

To start off the system has 3 files. One .css stylesheet, the .html page, and the .js script.

**.css stylesheet**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: "Optima Nova";
  src: url('fonts/eot/OptimaNovaLT-Black.eot');
  src: url('fonts/eot/OptimaNovaLT-Black.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/woff2/OptimaNovaLT-Black.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('fonts/woff/OptimaNovaLT-Black.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/ttf/OptimaNovaLT-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
}

#chatBody * {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}

#anchor {
  overflow-anchor: auto;
  height: 10px;
}

html {
  background: #cc0000;
  font-family: "Optima Nova","Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100.001vh;
  text-align: center;
}

a:link {
  color:rgb(46, 46, 46);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flipX {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

**.html file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Persona SMS Simulation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="chatBody">
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <img src="images/scrolling.png">
    <div id="Credit">Orignal project by <a href="#">nutty7t</a>.<br>Edited by CerebralPolicy (u/harperofthefreenorth)</div>
    <div id="chat">
    <!--insert new-->
    </div>
    <script id="chat-thread" type="x-template">
        <div v-if="window.devicePixelRatio === 1">
            <br/>
            <ChatMessage
                v-for="message in messages"
                ref="chatMessages"
                :message="message.text"
                :remote="message.remote"
                :chatter="message.chatter"
                :consecutive="message.consecutive"
        />
        </div>
        <div v-else style="margin: 20px; color: white">
            <h1>Oops, my bad...</h1>
            <p>
                Your <code>window.devicePixelRatio</code> does not equal <code>1</code>. This means that the ratio between physical pixels and logical pixels don't have a 1-to-1 correspondence on your display device. I have yet to (and probably never will) implement pixel scaling for these ratios. If you're on a mobile device, try viewing this on a desktop computer; but not on a Retina or HiDPI display.
            </p>
            <p>- (nutty7t)</p>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script id="chat-message" type="x-template">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="`0 0 500 ${viewBoxHeight}`" :style="style">
            <!--
                HACK: This invisible <text> element is used to figure out
                the bounding box of a line of text without it being painted.
            -->
            <text
                ref="hackText"
                visibility="hidden"
                :style="{ fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }">{{ hackText }}</text>

            <!-- Buddy Avatar -->
        <a v-if="newChatter">
            <polygon
                v-if="remote"
                points="-10,-5 62,5 70,55 5,63"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                style="fill: black"/>

            <polygon
                v-if="remote"
                points="0,0 60,10 70,50 10,60"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                style="fill: white"/>

            <clipPath id="avatarClipPath">
            <polygon points="2,-10 62,-10 100,42 10,58"/>
            </clipPath>

        <!-- absolute dogshit workaround -->
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-if="chatter == 'Akechi'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Akechi.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Ann'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Ann.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Futaba'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Futaba.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
        <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Haru'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Haru.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Hifumi'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Hifumi.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Kasumi'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Kasumi.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Makoto'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Thing.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Ryuji'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Ryuji.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Sumire'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Sumire.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Yuskue'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Yuskue.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
            <image
                clip-path="url(#avatarClipPath)"
                v-else-if="chatter == 'Lavensa'"
                x="-10"
                y="-10"
                xlink:href="images\Lavensa.png"
                :transform="`translate(30,${containerHeight / 2 + messageBox.origin.y - 25})`"
                width="80px"
        />
        </a>

            <!-- Message Text Container Border -->
            <polygon
                :points="containerBorderPoints"
                :style="{ fill: primaryColor }"
                :class="{ flipX: !remote }"/>

            <!-- Message Text Container Tail Border -->
            <polygon
                :points="containerTailBorderPoints"
                :style="{ fill: primaryColor }"
                :class="{ flipX: !remote }"/>

            <!-- Message Text Container Tail -->
            <polygon
                :points="containerTailPoints"
                :style="{ fill: secondaryColor }"
                :class="{ flipX: !remote }"/>

            <!-- Message Text Container -->
            <polygon
                :points="containerPoints"
                :style="{ fill: secondaryColor }"
                :class="{ flipX: !remote }"/>

            <!-- Message Text -->
            <text :y="textOffset.y" :style="{ fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }">
                <tspan
                    v-for="line of wrappedMessage"
                    :x="remote ? messageBox.origin.x + textOffset.x : 500 - messageBox.origin.x - messageBox.centerWidth"
                    :dy="`${lineHeight}em`"
                    :style="{ fill: primaryColor }">
                    {{ line.text }}
                </tspan>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </script>
    <!-- partial -->
 <div id="anchor"></div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-async-computed@3.7.0'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**.js script**

```js
const ChatMessage = {
  template: '#chat-message',
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },

    remote: {
      // Comment by Nutty7t:
      // Does the message originate from a remote source?
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },

    chatter: {
      // Used to grab chat image
      type: String
    },

    newChatter: {
      // TODO: Hide picture if same chatter sends multiple messages in a row
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },

    messageWait: {
      // How long before the next message
      type: Number,
      default: 2000 // in ms
    },

    fontSize: {
      type: Number,
      default: 14 },

    lineHeight: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1.5 // em
    } },

  data() {
    return {
      hackText: '',
      style: {
        opacity: 0 } };

    
  },
  computed: {
    // Comment by Nutty7t:
    // ------------------------------------------
    //         Message Box (remote: true)
    // ------------------------------------------
    //
    //   origin                            x - right width
    //       \ [ ---- center width ---- ]  |
    //         x----------------------- x --- x
    //       / |     <message text>     |   /
    //     /   |                        | /
    //   x --- x ---------------------- x
    //      |
    //      + - left width
    //
    messageBox() {
      return {
        origin: {
          x: this.remote ? 130 : 60,
          y: 20 },

        centerWidth: 300,
        leftWidth: 10,
        rightWidth: 20,
        slantHeight: 5,
        border: {
          normal: 4,
          left: 15,
          right: 35 } };


    },
    textOffset() {
      return {
        // Comment by Nutty7t:
        // Left padding.
        x: 15,
        // Adjust for top/bottom padding.
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.fontSize * this.lineHeight / 4 };

    },
    containerPoints() {
      return [
      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x + this.messageBox.centerWidth + this.messageBox.rightWidth,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x + this.messageBox.centerWidth,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight + this.messageBox.slantHeight },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - this.messageBox.leftWidth,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight }].

      map(p => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(' ');
    },
    containerBorderPoints() {
      return [
      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - this.messageBox.border.normal,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y - this.messageBox.border.normal },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x + this.messageBox.centerWidth + this.messageBox.border.right,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y - this.messageBox.border.normal },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x + this.messageBox.centerWidth + this.messageBox.border.normal,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight + this.messageBox.border.normal + this.messageBox.slantHeight },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - this.messageBox.border.left,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight + this.messageBox.border.normal }].

      map(p => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(' ');
    },
    containerTailPoints() {
      return [
      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 33,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 8 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 17,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 10 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 12,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 4 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 10 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 5 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 18,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 10 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 22,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 5 }].

      map(p => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(' ');
    },
    containerTailBorderPoints() {
      return [
      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 40,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 12 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 15,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 16 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 12,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 10 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 - 15 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 10 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 20,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 15 },

      {
        x: this.messageBox.origin.x - 24,
        y: this.messageBox.origin.y + this.containerHeight / 2 + 10 }].

      map(p => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(' ');
    },
    containerHeight() {
      // Comment by Nutty7t:
      // Compute how much vertical space the message text takes up by
      // multiplying the line height by the number of lines in the message.
      let height = this.fontSize * this.lineHeight * this.wrappedMessage.length;
      // Comment by Nutty7t:
      // Now, we need to add some extra bottom padding otherwise the
      // descenders (the part of the characters beneath the baseline)
      // will get clipped. I don't know the exact height of the descender,
      // but I figure that 1/2 em should be fine. And then we'll add another
      // 1/4 em for top and bottom paddings (1/2 em in total).
      //
      //   ---
      //    |   top padding (1/4 em)
      //   ---
      //    |   text height (line height * # of lines)
      //   ---
      //    |   descender padding (1/2 em)
      //   ---
      // .  |   slanted bottom edge (this.messageBox.slantHeight)
      //   ---
      //    |   bottom padding (1/4 em)
      //   ---
      //
      return height + this.fontSize * this.lineHeight;
    },
    viewBoxHeight() {
      // Comment by Nutty7t:
      //
      //   ---
      //    |   border width
      //   ---
      //    |   container height
      //   ---
      //    |   border width
      //   ---
      //
      return this.containerHeight + this.messageBox.origin.y * 2;
    },
    primaryColor() {
      return this.remote ? 'white' : 'black';
    },
    secondaryColor() {
      return this.remote ? 'black' : 'white';
    } },

  asyncComputed: {
    wrappedMessage: {
      async get() {
        // Comment by Nutty7t:
        // Kind of a hacky way of implementing word wrapping
        // on SVG <text> elements. Not quite sure how to go
        // about determining the bounding box of some text,
        // without actually rendering it on the DOM.
        const words = this.message.split(/\s+/);
        const lines = [];
        let line = [];
        while (words.length > 0) {
          line.push(words.shift());
          this.hackText = line.join(' ');
          if ((await this.hackTextWidth()) > this.messageBox.centerWidth) {
            words.unshift(line.pop());
            lines.push({ text: line.join(' ') });
            line = [];
          }
        }
        lines.push({ text: line.join(' ') });
        if (lines.length === 1) {
          // Messages that are only one line have a fluid width.
          this.messageBox.centerWidth = (await this.hackTextWidth()) + this.textOffset.x * 2;
        }
        return lines;
      },
      default: [] } },


  methods: {
    async hackTextWidth() {
      // Wait until #hackText is rendered in the DOM.
      while (!this.$refs.hackText) {
        await Vue.nextTick();
      }
      // Wait for Vue to update the innerHTML of #hackText.
      await Vue.nextTick();
      if (this.$refs.hackText.innerHTML === this.hackText) {
        return this.$refs.hackText.clientWidth;
      } else {
        console.log(
        `[error] hackText does not have expected text\n` +
        `        expected: "${this.hackText}"\n` +
        `        actual:   "${this.$refs.hackText.innerHTML}"`);

        return 0;
      }
    } },

  mounted() {
    TweenMax.to(this.style, 1, {
      opacity: 1,
      ease: Power3.easeOut });

  } };


const ChatThread = new Vue({
  el: '#chat',
  template: '#chat-thread',
  components: { ChatMessage },
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [],
      queue: [
    //format
    //  text: what is sent  [nutty7t]
    //  chatter: who sent it [cerebralpolicy]
    //  remote: is it someone other than POV [nutty7t]
    //  messageWait: how long before next reply [cerebralpolicy]
      {
        text: "Message 1",
        chatter: 'Haru',
        remote: true,
        messageWait: 1000
      },

      {
        text: 'Message 2',
        chatter: 'Ryuji',
        remote: true, 
        messageWait: 2000
      },

      {
        text: "Message 3",
        chatter: 'Makoto',
        remote: true,
        messageWait: 1500
      },

      ],


      interval: undefined };

  },
  watch: {
    async messages(newMessages, oldMessages) {
      if (this.queue.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      await Vue.nextTick();
      const messages = this.$refs.chatMessages;
      const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
      // possible mechanisms?      
//    const thisMessage = messages[messages.length];
//    var delayMessage = thisMessage.messageWait;
      // display indicator someone is typing

      if (document.body !== null) {
        TweenMax.to(window, 1, { scrollTo: { y: document.body.scrollHeight }, ease: Power3.easeOut });
      }
    } },

  mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.messages.push(this.queue.shift());
    }, 2000); // Need to pass messageWait value here
  } 
});

document.scrollingElement.scroll(0, 1);
```

My instinct was to format the chatThread block as follows.

```js
const ChatThread = new Vue({
  el: '#chat',
  template: '#chat-thread',
  components: { ChatMessage },
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [],
      queue: [
    //format
    //  text: what is sent  [nutty7t]
    //  chatter: who sent it [cerebralpolicy]
    //  remote: is it someone other than POV [nutty7t]
    //  messageWait: how long before next reply [cerebralpolicy]
      {
        text: "Message 1",
        chatter: 'Haru',
        remote: true,
        messageWait: 1000 // I want to make Ryuji wait 1000ms before responding
      },

      {
        text: 'Message 2',
        chatter: 'Ryuji',
        remote: true, 
        messageWait: 2000 // I want to make Makoto wait 2000ms before responding
      },

      {
        text: "Message 3",
        chatter: 'Makoto',
        remote: true,
        messageWait: 1500 // and so on
      },

      ],


      interval: undefined };

  },
  watch: {
    async messages(newMessages, oldMessages) {
      if (this.queue.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      await Vue.nextTick();
      const messages = this.$refs.chatMessages;
      const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
      // possible mechanisms?      
//    const thisMessage = messages[messages.length];
//    var delayMessage = thisMessage.messageWait;
      // display indicator someone is typing

      if (document.body !== null) {
        TweenMax.to(window, 1, { scrollTo: { y: document.body.scrollHeight }, ease: Power3.easeOut });
      }
    } },

  mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.messages.push(this.queue.shift());
    }, this.lastMessage.messageWait); 
// I expected that it would break the first message but instead it appears to grab a value of 0ms 
// all messages display instantly. The first message doesn't break, surprisingly.
  } 
});
```

I'm not sure if javascript can do what I have outlined. I highly suspect it can but I am not familiar with it nor the Vue template system. Can anyone assist me?